# if and else else condition both condition is running problem

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I am able to filter date according to selected date of calendar but along with the filter icons are also showing which should not be shown where list is shown need help.This is the code everything is working but the problem is i am getting list also the cannot show list icon also meaning else icon are also being shown. when list is there else condition should not be shown but it is also showing meaning both if and else condition is running at the same time

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: homeworkSnapshot.data.map((homework){
                                          if(dateController.text == homework.savedHomeworkSubmissionDate){
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                  .symmetric(vertical: 3),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.105,
                                                child: GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                                        .pushReplacement(
                                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                                            builder: (ctx)=>HomeworkPostScreen(
                                                                  savedHomeworkId: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkId,
                                                                  savedHomeworkCName: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkClassName,
                                                                  savedHomeworkSName: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkSectionName,
                                                                  savedHomeworkSubName: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkSubjectName,
                                                                  savedHomeworkT: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkTitle,
                                                                  savedHomeworkL: homework
                                                                      .link,
                                                                  savedHomeworkD: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkDetail,
                                                                  savedHomeworkImgs: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkImage,
                                                                  savedHomeworkSD: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkSubmissionDate,
                                                                )));
                                                  },
                                                  child: Card(
                                                    elevation: 0.0,
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                          .symmetric(
                                                          horizontal: 10,
                                                          vertical: 5),
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                            .start,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Padding(
                                                            padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                                .symmetric(
                                                                horizontal: 10),
                                                            child: Column(
                                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                  .start,
                                                              children: [
                                                                const SizedBox(
                                                                    height: 5),
                                                                Text(homework
                                                                    .savedHomeworkTitle),
                                                                const SizedBox(
                                                                    height: 50),
                                                                Row(
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    const Text(
                                                                      "Deadline :",
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                          color: Colors
                                                                              .black38),),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                      homework
                                                                          .savedHomeworkSubmissionDate,
                                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                                          color: Colors
                                                                              .black38),)
                                                                  ],
                                                                )
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                          ),

                                                          const SizedBox(
                                                              width: 70),
                                                          Container(
                                                            height: 100,
                                                            width: 1,
                                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                                          ),

                                                          Expanded(
                                                            child: Padding(
                                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                                  horizontal: 10),
                                                              child: Column(
                                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                children: [
                                                                  Text(homework.savedHomeworkSubjectName ??" ",
                                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                        fontSize: 14),
                                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),
                                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                                      height: 20),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    "Class: ",
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: ColorCombination(0).appBarColor),),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    "${homework.savedHomeworkClassName ??" "}(${homework.savedHomeworkSectionName ??" "})",
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: ColorCombination(0).appBarColor),),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );

                                          }else{
                                          return  Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200),
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Image.asset("icons/empty_homework_icon.png"),
                                                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                                                  const Text("Homework List Not Found",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                                  const Text("Looks like there are no homework record for the",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),),
                                                  const Text("day",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),)
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                          }
                                        }).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    );
```

Comment: Can you simplify the code-snippet?

Comment: the thing is in the line where i wrote condition if(dateController.text == homework.savedHomeworkSubmissionDate) when the condition is meet the list is shown but after if there is else condition which should be shown if the condition doesnt meet but even if the if condition is true else condition is also running and that icon is also showing with the list of data

Comment: Sorry, this question contains some data that isnt included in question, can you provide a simple version of code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: ok let me ask a question again and i will provide you the link

Comment: you can edit and update this question

Comment: ohh ok thanks i will do that now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241652/discussion-between-sujan-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Comment: When this happens? The first time this screen displayed or when you select date?

Comment: this happens when i add data into two different date like today date and yestarday date

Comment: Okay, i guess if-else block doesn't run at the same time because this is not possible. They're running seperately according to the conditions. However when you create a list, they display at the same time on the screen

Comment: so meaning i have to first create a function to get list according to date and render it on screen??